# Code to search/filter data in a data grid view in VS C# not working as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, datagridview, filter

This is the tutorial I'm using: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6NnrIXN6dY

And here is the relevant code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(senior_playersDataTable);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("first_name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    senior_playersDataGridView.DataSource = DV;
}
```

My DataTable is called "senior_playersDataTable"

My DataGridView is called "senior_playersDataGridView"

The column is called "first_name"

The gist of the tutorial is to declare the relevant DataTable globally, then create a Dataview and filter it by text entered into a textbox, then set the data source to the new, filtered, gridview.

The problem is typing anything into the text box hides all the data and rows.  Them emptying the text box does not bring them back.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Additionally, if I wanted to search more than 1 column at a time with a single text box, is that as simple as repeating DV.RowFilter line like so?

```
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(senior_playersDataTable);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("first_name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("column2 LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("column3 LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);

    senior_playersDataGridView.DataSource = DV;
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your filter code seems to be fine. You need to debug it and check if it is called and what is the RowFilter expression

Comment: I ran through and the program definitely executes each line.  I seem to have the syntax right for the RowFilter, not sure what's going on.